# dynamic_cast doubt from C++/Stroustrup : converting to protected base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-cast

I know that following code gives compilation error :

```
class A{ public : virtual void name(){cout<<typeid(this).name()<<endl;}; };
class B:protected A{public : virtual void name(){cout<<typeid(this).name()<<endl;};};
void foo(B* b)
{
    A * a = dynamic_cast<A*>(b); //Error : 'A' is an inaccessible base of 'B'    
    return;
}
```

But then why in the C++ Stroustrup book (15.4.1) he writes

```
class BB_ival_slider:public Ival_slider,protected BBslider{ //...
};
void f(BB_ival_slider*p)
{  
// ok 
BBslider* pbb2 = dynamic_cast<BBslider*>(p);    // ok: pbb2 becomes 0
}
```

Shouldn't the line be compilation error  ?
So either my gcc is wrong in flagging it as compilation error OR the unthinkable, stroustrup typo or most plausibly I have missed something...

Comment: Interesting question - note that this fails even if the base is virtual, and a sub-subclass derives via `public virtual` from the same base... I'd like to see a C++ standard citation on why compilers can reject this.

Comment: I am lazy. :(  I usually follow Stroustrup's word as standard. :)
But I think there is a need to open that worlds most dry and boring standard-report for such a lively language.

Comment: @bdonlan: 5.2.7 para 5, says regarding `dynamic_cast<B*>(pointer_to_class_D)` that "`B` shall be an **accessible** unambiguous base class of `D`" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @David, what if B is not a base class of D at all? Consider C derives from B and A; we should be able to dynamic_cast from a B * to an instance of C to its A base, or for that matter or its C superclass. Neither A nor C is an accessible unambiguous base class of B.

Comment: @bdonlan: The word "unambiguous" here is with respect to the diamond problem. Suppose `D` inherits from `B` and `C`, each of which in turn inherits non-virtually from `A`. The conversion from `D*` to `A*` is ambiguous.

Comment: @David, I'm not concerned about "unambiguous" so much as the restriction to "base class"es...

Comment: @bdonlan: Sorry, I snipped too much. 5.2.7 para 5 is about upcasting (which is the context of this question). That paragraph starts with "*If `T`is “pointer to `cv1 B`” and `v` has type “pointer to `cv2 D`” such that `B` is a base class of `D`, ...*". Downcasting via `dynamic_cast` is covered by 5.2.7 para 8.

Comment: @david, ah, okay then, that makes more sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual quote from 15.4.1 is:

> ```
> class BB_ival_slider : public Ival_slider, protected BBslider {
>     // ...
> };
>
> void f(BB_ival_slider* p)
> {
>     Ival_slider* pi1 = p; // ok
>     Ival_slider* pi2 = dynamic_cast<Ival_slider*>(p); // ok
>     BBslider* pbb1 = p; // error: BBslider is a protected base
>     BBslider* pbb2 = dynamic_cast<BBslider*>(p); // ok: pbb2 becomes 0
> }
> ```
>
> That is the uninteresting case. However, it is reassuring to know that **`dynamic_cast` doesn't allow accidental violation of the protection of private and protected base classes**.

So it would seem that the text describing the code is correct, but for the wrong reasons -- `dynamic_cast` **doesn't** allow accidental violation of the protection of private and protected base classes, but only because using it would be ill-formed and will result in a compiler error, not because using it will yield a null-pointer. And, of course, the code the text is describing is **definitely** *in*correct.

Mistakes happen -- maybe it will be fixed in the 4th edition of the book. :-]

(Also, note that if `BB_ival_slider` declares `f` to be a `friend`, then the code **will** behave as described in the book. Perhaps this `friend` declaration was implied earlier in the chapter, but I don't have time right now to read over it carefully to check one way or the other.)

Comment: Wow, I would love to get hold of whatever you used to copy that content from book. What do you have ?  PDF or some ebook ?

Comment: @Ajeet : I looked at my hard copy and typed it out, since it was short. If I had an ebook, I could search the chapter for the word `friend` and answer the question raised in my last paragraph. ;-]

Comment: Cool, you are my type, who keeps Stroustrup within arms reach on his desktop ?

Comment: @Ajeet : Indeed, always, as well as Sutter, Meyers, and Josuttis' books. :-]

Comment: Sutter is fine. That guy can find unobvious and almost undetectable things. But do you ever refer meyers after Stroustrup ?  :)

Comment: @Ajeet : My personal opinion is that Stroustrup is more interesting/entertaining to read than he is informative (in a practical respect). I.e., I would turn to a Meyers book _before_ a Stroustrup book if I were looking for something specific.

Comment: hmm. I too dont like  Stroustrups content arrangement anyways. But hey, he is the only one who assures you, you can derive everything rest from this book. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps he tested that code, perhaps not. (Lots of authors put untested code in their books.) If he did test it, keep in mind that not all compilers are created equal. g++ fails with `error: 'BBslider' is an inaccessible base of 'BB_ival_slider'`. clang fails with `error: cannot cast 'BB_ival_slider' to its protected base class 'BBslider'`. Other compilers: Who knows? Every compiler I know of has some problem with compliance with the standard.

Comment: Umm, we are talking about stroustrup here....
Standards reflect his mind. Not vice versa. :P

Answer (score 0):

I think if I am not finding any constructive evidence then I might just say

"Stroustrup was wrong"  (that sounds scary :( )

I dont think compilers are allowed to spill the guts of class internal willingly(by defined standard). Unless they are put through knife. (evil pointer operation that is)

Comment: By "evil pointer operation", I assume you mean the evil C-style cast. And yes, a C-style cast can convert a derived class pointer to a base class pointer, "*even if the base class type is not accessible*" (5.4 para 7). The result of this evil operation is not a null pointer.

Comment: @David Yes, yes. There is no cure to that kind of c-style black magic. :)
If someone has used it, then only the one who "cast" it, alone will be able to undo it reliably. hehehe