# C++ dynamic_ptr_cast of a shared_ptr from a base to derived fails

Tags: c++, polymorphism, shared-ptr

This is a puzzler I ran across this week.  It's partly due to the fact that I have just returned to C++ coding after coding Java for a while.  Given the following code:

```
class Base {
};

class A : Base {
public:
    virtual void run() { cout << "This is A." << endl; }
};
class B : Base {
public:
   virtual void run() { cout << "This is B." << endl; }
};

class C : A, B {
public:
   void run() { cout << "This is C." << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   shared_ptr<A> ptrToA = shared_ptr<C>(new C());

   cout << "Pointer to A: " << ptrToA.get() << endl;
   cout << "Dynamic Cast A ptr to C: " << dynamic_pointer_cast<C>(ptrToA) << endl;

   ptrToA->run();

   assert(dynamic_pointer_cast<C>(ptrToA));
   cout << "Success!" << endl;
}
```

Why does it produce the following output?

```
Pointer to A: 0x1f29c010
Dynamic Cast A ptr to C: 0
Running...
This is C.
tester-cpp: tester.cpp:89: int main(int, char **): Assertion `dynamic_pointer_cast<C>(ptrToA)' failed.
```

Because "This is C" prints out, it's obvious that the polymorphism is working, but it fails when dynamic casting a shared_ptr from the "A" base class to a "C".  I wasted hours of time on this subtle issue this week!  Hopefully any answers will save future coders with a similar issue from wasting so much time (the bug was very subtle, especially after coding Java for a while).

Why?  (I'll give you a hint...this code was compiled with the Intel C++ compiler 12.1.0 on Linux.  I tried it with another compiler and my code is *fails to compile!*)

Comment: Because `C` _privately_ inherits from `A` and `B`; change `class C : A, B` to `class C : public A, public B` or `struct C : A, B`. Also, "This is C" prints out when using an `A*` but I suspect it would not when using a `B*`; `run()` probably needs to be initially declared inside of `Base`, and you probably need to use virtual inheritance.

Comment: What implementation of `shared_ptr` are you using?  I would expect `shared_ptr<A> ptrToA = shared_ptr<C>(new C());` to fail because `A` is an inaccessible base of `C`.

Comment: You should try it without the smart pointers and then I suspect that this may apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210321/dynamic-cast-doubt-from-c-stroustrup-converting-to-protected-base-class

Comment: gcc fails to compile with "error: conversion from ‘std::shared_ptr<C>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::shared_ptr<A>’ requested" as I believe it should.

Comment: Ironically, our makefiles were set up to pull in the g++ implementation of std::tr1::shared_ptr!  When compiled with gcc, my 4.5 gives the error " ‘A’ is an inaccessible base of ‘C’", which makes the problem very obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that it fails to compile on another compiler is a hint: It really should fail to compile. This is because `C` privately inherits from `A` and `B`, so `C*` should not be convertible to `A*`. Therefore `shared_ptr<A> ptrToA = shared_ptr<C>(new C());` should fail to compile, since the conversation constructor should only participate in overload resolution when the pointer can be converted according to the standard. So this looks like a bug in the standard library used by Intel C++.

Change `Class C: A, B` to `Class C: public A, public B` and it should work. Testing on gcc 4.6, the code indeed fails to compile with private inheritance and works just as it should with public inheritance of `A`.

Since your code contains a [diamond inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem), you might also want to take a look at [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance).

Comment: Nicely put, and yes, my original code did not have virtual inheritance on "Base" (I was thinking more java interfaces at the time...), but probably should.